# CSS line that will expand off screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that has lines on either end of it like this :

[image]

I am trying to make the line infinite so no matter how much I zoom out it looks like the line is coming from the end of the screen without the size of the image changing.

I know I can do a white line using repeat-x but I'm having trouble trying to get the outsize div to overlap the screen without affecting the image. I'm using bootstrap.

Here is my code for the image

```
<div class="row">
               <div class="col-xl-12 hscentertext" style="">
                 <img src="assets/img/25k.png" class="img-fluid center-block text-xl-center" alt="Responsive image"> 
                <!--  <canvas id="canvas" class="fullonly" width="800" height="133" style="background-color:#D32225"></canvas> -->
               </div>
            </div>
```

Can someone please assist with how I can achieve this effect?

Comment: How are you creating the line?

Comment: is the line part of the image?

Comment: For css: `width:110%;overflow:hidden` but need to see how you're doing it to see if this makes sense in your case.

Comment: I would assume it's part of the image since the line isn't under the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using **110% on your width**, like so:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  width:110%
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My ideea is to crop you image to be without border. After that use CSS:

```
.col-xl-12.hscentertext {
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.img-fluid.center-block.text-xl-center { 
     margin-bottom: -1px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice your image in 4 vertical parts:

1) empty red space+few pixels of rounded head of white horizontal line

2) vertical line of 1px width for repeating the line in bg

3) main part with logo

4) empty red space+few pixels of rounded tail of white horizontal line

then you split your markup in 5 vertical divs:

1,3,5 with fixed width and centered background-image

and 2,4 - for "repeat-x" 1-pixel bg with width: calc(50% - #(logo+head+tail)/2#px);
value inside ## calculate yourself